# React-tabulator looses scroll/selection after replaceData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I am using react-tabulator 0.14.2 and tabulator-tables 4.9.3.

The data I display in my Tabulator is always changing, but I cannot find how to refresh it without scrolling back to the top and loosing the selected line(s)

```
  const columns = [
    { title: 'First', field: 'fname', width: 120, formatter: 'textarea' },
    { title: 'Last', field: 'lname', width: 120, formatter: 'textarea' },
  ];

  const options = {
    selectable: 1,
    rowClick,
    invalidOptionWarnings: false,
    index: 'usid',
    maxHeight: '100%',
  };

  <ReactTabulator
    ref={listRef}
    data={[]}
    columns={columns}
    layout="fitColumns"
    options={options}
  />
```

(my table has more columns but even this stripped down version fails).

I have tried:

- setting directly the data in the element props, `data={dataSrc}` instead of `data={[]}`: this triggers a noticeable full table redraw each time
- calling `listRef.current.table.updateOrAddData(dataSrc)`
- calling `listRef.current.table.replaceData(dataSrc)`

In all these cases, when my table is too long, it scrolls back to the top, and the selected row gets deselected upon refresh.

If I use `listRef.current.table.selectRow(...);` after a refresh, then I am able to preserve the selected row, BUT the table still scrolls back to the top.

I have tried playing with the `scrollVertical` tabulator callback, but this only gives the vertical scrolling position. I can read this just before an update, but I don't see how to restore that scroll position after refreshing the data.

The behaviour I see doesn't match the Tabulator specs http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update#alter-replace :

> The replaceData function lets you silently replace all data in the table without updating scroll position, sort or filtering, and without triggering the ajax loading popup.

Any suggestion on how to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the scrollVertical callback tells you the scroll position.

You can use this to reset the position by using the rowManager.element.scrollTop property.  It worked for me.

Based on your description, it would be something like this ...
listRef.current.table.rowManager.element.scrollTop = YOUR_SAVED_VALUE_FROM_scrollVertical_CALLBACK

EDIT - Note: I did this in the promise resolve function after the replaceData call.  If you try to do this directly after the replaceData call, it isn't done yet and won't work.

More Edits: Working on this I noticed that if I do not apply a filter after the table data is loaded then I don't have an issue.  It was the use of addFilter which I was using for other technical reasons to filter out some data every time.  When I removed that action, then doing a simple replaceData did not cause the position to reset.  There was no reason to re-apply the same filter as replaceData take into account the filters in place, this was really a bug in my own code causing it to jump to the top, the library code works as designed.

Answer (score 0):

The *replaceData* function lets you silently replace all data in the table **without updating scroll position, sort or filtering, and without triggering the ajax loading popup.**

You have not shown your own code. Maybe the scroll is being called by something else in your code.