# Dynamicaly adding and removing css class to tabulator grid cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, tabulator

I would like to "select" a column in a table created with Tabulator grid. What I want to achieve is adding a css class to selected column:

[image]

I have tried to do so by adding cellClick function (please see the snipplet). I am able to change the cell elements html style and change the color. But I would like to add a css class: "column-selected" to every cell from selected colum. I also wonder if there is any more elegant solution than adding **onCellClick** function?

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
];


var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
     data:tabledata, //assign data to table
     columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob"},
    ],
    columnDefaults:{
        cellClick:function(e, cell){
            cell.getColumn().getCells().forEach(function(cell){
               cell.getElement().style.color = "#A6A6DF";
            })
        },
    },
});
```

```css
.column-selected {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `cell.classList.add("column-selected");`?

Comment: How is it not working currently?

Comment: @Pointy I tried   cell.getElement().classList.add("column-selected"); and indeed it worked. Please mind the fact that I am beginning my journey with javascript so smth obvious for you was very difficult for me to find (I tried to play around in console but did not found this option)

Comment: Looks like for this you need to monitor the scroll position using a callback: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68147423/15273968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getColumn().updateDefinition({cssClass: "column-selected"})`:

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
];


var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
     data:tabledata, //assign data to table
     columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob"},
    ],
    columnDefaults:{
        cellClick:function(e, cell){
          if(cell.getElement().classList.contains("column-selected")) {
            cell.getColumn().updateDefinition({cssClass: ""});
          } else {
            cell.getColumn().updateDefinition({cssClass: "column-selected"});
          }
        },
    },
});
```

```css
.column-selected {
  color:red;
  background: #ff03;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Click column one more time to un-select it.

Comment: That is much more elegant solution than mine. Do you know maybe also how to remove the "column-selected" class in in a similar fashion?

Comment: @fascynacja simple use `updateDefinition({cssClass: ""})`

Comment: That works indded. I thought if I use empty cssClass I will remove also the native "tabulator-cell" class, but I see it is not removed. Thanks for editing the answer as well.

Comment: I have applied those changes to my real table, which has much more data and it has also fixed height. Unfortunately I have a side effect, that after calling "updateDefinition" the table scrolls to top. You can try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/L6vnywpj/ . Do you know how to force the table to to scroll to the top after "selecting" a column?

Comment: Monitor the scroll position and use [`scrollToRow`](https://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/navigation#scroll-row)

Comment: I tried different combinations of calling this method: table.scrollToRow(cell.getRow().getIndex(), "bottom", false). But the final effect is not what I need. If I click the very bottom row the scroll does not scroll there. Also I needed to add   table.scrollToColumn( cell.getColumn().getField(), "middle", false); to maintain the vertical scroll and this worked well. I think I will create separate question for this problem.

Comment: I have posted a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653191/tabulator-grid-sccrolls-to-the-top-left-corner-after-updating-colum-definition-w

Answer (score -1):

To achieve your goal of adding a CSS class to every cell in a selected column, you can use the `cellClick` function to track which column is selected and then update the CSS class accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .column-selected {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>

    <script>
        var tabledata = [
            { id: 1, name: "Oli Bob", age: "12", col: "red", dob: "" },
            { id: 2, name: "Mary May", age: "1", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982" },
            { id: 3, name: "Christine Lobowski", age: "42", col: "green", dob: "22/05/1982" },
        ];

        var selectedColumn = null;

        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            data: tabledata, // assign data to table
            columns: [
                { title: "Name", field: "name" },
                { title: "Favourite Color", field: "col" },
                { title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob" },
            ],
            columnDefaults: {
                cellClick: function (e, cell) {
                    // Remove class from the previously selected column
                    if (selectedColumn) {
                        table.getColumns().forEach(function (column) {
                            column.getCells().forEach(function (cell) {
                                cell.getElement().classList.remove("column-selected");
                            });
                        });
                    }

                    // Add class to the clicked column
                    selectedColumn = cell.getColumn().getDefinition().field;
                    cell.getColumn().getCells().forEach(function (cell) {
                        cell.getElement().classList.add("column-selected");
                    });
                },
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, the `selectedColumn` variable is used to keep track of the currently selected column. The `cellClick` function is then modified to remove the "column-selected" class from the previously selected column and add it to the cells of the newly selected column.

if you want the previously clicked column remain selected. and only get unselected after clicking again you can use below cellClick function

```js
 cellClick: function (e, cell) {
            // Add class to the clicked column
        
            cell
              .getColumn()
              .getCells()
              .forEach(function (cell) {
                cell.getElement().classList.toggle("column-selected");
              });
          },
```

Comment: that is a ncie idea. Why we have to go through all the cells to "deselect" them? Isnt there a way to remember the column and its cells and remove the ccss class only from previously selected?

Comment: @fascynacja it's much much simpler just to deselect all of them. Browsers can do things like that very quickly.

Comment: @Pointy That is good to know, comming from backend I am used to optimize anything as much as possible:) I am struggling with this idea so I have posted separate more adequate question on the topic.