# Tabulator grid sccrolls to the top left corner after updating colum definition with updateDefinition({cssClass: ?});

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabulator

I have a table created with Tabulator grid. After clicking one of the cells of the column I am "selecting" it by changing its css style. With current implementation the problem I am observing is that the table "scrolls" back to the top left corner. You can see the simplified example in here:

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"1111 Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:"1"},
    {id:2, name:"2222 May", age:"1",  col:"blue", dob:"2/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"3333 Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"3/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"4444 Bob", age:"12", col:"pink", dob:"4"},
    {id:5, name:"5555 May", age:"1", col:"black", dob:"5/05/1982"},
    {id:6, name:"6666 Lobowski", age:"42", col:"white", dob:"6/05/1982"},
    {id:7, name:"7777 Lobowski", age:"42", col:"orange", dob:"7/05/1982"},
    {id:8, name:"8888 Bob", age:"12", col:"gray", dob:"8"},
    {id:9, name:"9999 May", age:"1", col:"gold", dob:"9/05/1982"}, 
];


var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
     data:tabledata, 
      height: "150px",
     columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob"},
    ],
    columnDefaults:{
        cellClick:function(e, cell){
          if(cell.getElement().classList.contains("column-selected")) {
            cell.getColumn().updateDefinition({cssClass: ""});
          } else {
            cell.getColumn().updateDefinition({cssClass: "column-selected"});
          }
        },
    },
});
```

```css
.column-selected {
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

In order to see the behaviour, please first scroll down to the bottom of the grid and select one cell. Effect is that the table scrolls to the top.
How can I avoid to scroll back? Why is it happening in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"1111 Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:"1"},
    {id:2, name:"2222 May", age:"1",  col:"blue", dob:"2/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"3333 Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"3/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"4444 Bob", age:"12", col:"pink", dob:"4"},
    {id:5, name:"5555 May", age:"1", col:"black", dob:"5/05/1982"},
    {id:6, name:"6666 Lobowski", age:"42", col:"white", dob:"6/05/1982"},
    {id:7, name:"7777 Lobowski", age:"42", col:"orange", dob:"7/05/1982"},
    {id:8, name:"8888 Bob", age:"12", col:"gray", dob:"8"},
    {id:9, name:"9999 May", age:"1", col:"gold", dob:"9/05/1982"}, 
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data: tabledata, 
    height: "150px",
    columns: [
        {title: "Name", field: "name"},
        {title: "Favourite Color", field: "col"},
        {title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob"},
    ],
});

// Add click event handling after the table is created
document.querySelectorAll('#example-table .tabulator-cell').forEach(function(cell) {
    cell.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var column = table.getColumn(cell.getAttribute('tabulator-field'));
        if (cell.classList.contains("column-selected")) {
            column.updateDefinition({ cssClass: "" });
        } else {
            column.updateDefinition({ cssClass: "column-selected" });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.column-selected {
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you post your solution included to my code snippet? When I tried to add this line it did not solve the issue. You can use the "Copy snippet to answer" button.

Comment: try now, its updated

Comment: It does not work either. Could you add the snippet as I advised before?

Comment: sorry for that now I added snippet code

Comment: This snipplet does not work. The column color is not updated to gray.

Comment: Wall of code usually don't make good answers. Provide some explanations of the key parts of your code and how they provide a solution to the question being asked.

Comment: If am I wrong please correct me, well your question was related to (How can I avoid scrolling back?), I think the issue is solved, so now another issue is related to selected column need to be gray color right ?

Comment: e.preventDefault();: This prevents the default action of the click event. In this case, it prevents the default behavior of a link, button, or table.